# Floating point math in macro constants, while maintaining integer-ness

Tags: c, macros

I have some macros like the following:

```
#define THING_LENGTH (512)
#define MAX_COUNT (4096*8)
#define MAX_LENGTH ((int32)((float)(MAX_COUNT*THING_LENGTH)*1.5))
```

Which are being substituted in this:

```
typedef struct Writes {
    char buf[MAX_LENGTH];
    char buf2[MAX_COUNT];
    ...
} Writes;
```

To give this preprocessed result:

```
typedef struct Writes {
    char buf[((int32)((float)((4096*8)*(512))*1.5))];
    char buf2[(4096*8)];
    ...
} Writes;
```

Which is giving me this warning/error:

```
variably modified ‘buf’ at file scope
```

What's the best way to maintain the MAX_COUNT*THING_LENGTH*1.5 logic in the macro, but have it work? And maintain all the constants as constant, and integer?

Answer (score 2):

Just don't use any float in math operations of constants. Here:

```
//---mul by 3, then div by 2
#define MAX_LENGTH ((MAX_COUNT*THING_LENGTH * 3) / 2 )

//---more optimized version
#define MAX_LENGTH_PARTIAL (MAX_COUNT*THING_LENGTH)
#define MAX_LENGTH (((MAX_LENGTH_PARTIAL << 1 ) + MAX_LENGTH_PARTIAL) >> 1 )
```

Comment: Don't use the _optimized version_. This is a preprocessor macro. For both versions the compiler will see some arithmetic with constants and will reduce that arithmetic to a single number. In other words, the _optimized version_ will not be faster, and it's hard to read.

Comment: Actually, there is no performance difference for the 2 version since they are all converted to a single number. I forgot that they are all constants so the bit shifting is unnecessary. :D But if someone uses a (num * 3 / 2) expression with variables, the optimized version should help.

Answer (score 2):

This question is duplicated many times.

The issue is that either:
1. floating point constants are not consider that *constant* for array size determination *and/or*
2. The array size is from a variable. (but not in this OP's case)

Note: remember that using `(x*3)/2` idiom instead of `(x*1.5)` truncates toward 0, so if `x` was `7`, `(x*3)/2` would be `10` and not `11`.  Depending on what you want, you may want `(x*3 + 1)/2` to insure ample `MAX_LENGTH`.